Invalid character in header content while opening React Native project

I created two project before this error. I faced this with my second project and decided creating a new project but it doesn't work. I tried to change statusPageMiddleware.js in project's file and again was not the right solution. How can I fix that?

I fixed that. Changed my files which contain unvalid characters and fixed it.

How did you fix that exactly?
